# Flow type error when using React.Node

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have written a utility function that I like but for some reason I am unable to get achieve the flow typing for it. The below code is producing errors.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';

export const partializeComponent = (partialProps: any) =>
  (Component: Node) =>
    (props: any): Node => (
      <Component
        {...partialProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
```

Since the error was very verbose, I have taken a screenshot instead[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is you're using the type `Node` incorrectly when applied to your argument component. The type `Node` represents a JSX element e.g. .... It is the correct return type for a React components render method.

In fact you should use the type `ComponentType` and a pass a Prop type to reflect the component's implementation.

I've updated your example, filled in some blanks for you to get on your way.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import type { ComponentType, Node } from 'react';

type PartialProps = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: number,
};

type Props = PartialProps & {
  otherProps: string,
};

export const partializeComponent = (partialProps: PartialProps) =>
  (Component: ComponentType<Props>) =>
    (props: Props): Node => (
      <Component
        {...partialProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
```

Please note this is not tested, it's from memory.

Comment: Ah I see where my confusion lies. `Node` is for the return type of the render method while `ComponentType<Something>` is for the render method per se.

Comment: That’s right, caught me out before as well. Please tick to accept answer if this has helped with your problem.