# Validating Object Map using Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```js
// @flow

import React from 'react';

type IconMap = {
  [name: string]: {}
};

export const icons: IconMap = {
  circle: {
    viewbox: '0 0 473.66 473.66',
    path(props) {
      return (
        <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" {...props}>
          <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <circle cx="236.83" cy="236.83" r="236.83" />
          </g>
        </g>
      );
    }
  }
};
```

First, how can I make the type `IconMap` above not accept an unsealed object as a value, but `{ viewbox: string, path: function }` instead?

Second, if I'm trying to call `icons` as follows:

`const obj = icons['circle']`

How can I make sure the above fails at compile-time if `circle` is *not* one of the keys of `icons`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question you can do:

```
type IconMap = {
  [name: string]: {|
    viewbox: string,
    path: Object => React$Node
  |}
};
```

For your second question, it's not possible to do that at compile time as far as I know.

`React$Node` is defined [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L12), and ships with Flow by default. Alternatively you could

```
import type {Node} from 'react
```

Comment: Thank you! Did you mean to write `React.Node`? For the second part, can I at least loop on `icons` object keys at runtime and provide a default if the given string is none of those keys?

Comment: @Sammy Yeah, but that's something you just do with regular JS. No need to do it with flow. Also I think `React$Node` might be hardcoded into Flow lol. Try it out.

Comment: @Sammy https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L12 Although `React.Node` might be more proper.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out what the error might be. When I try `React.Node` I get `Error:(8, 27) Cannot get React.Node because property Node is missing in object type [1].`

Comment: @sammy I got the same thing which is why I used the `$` variant which means the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780001/flow-type-error-when-using-react-node addresses your issue. TL;DR `import type {Node} from 'react'`

Comment: Thank you, I just have no idea where this `$` variant comes from! Do you happen to have a link that explains what it is please?

Comment: @Sammy I linked it to you in a comment above. https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L12 it ships by default with the flow library as a global typedef.

Comment: @Sammy no need to apologize. It is confusing. Glad I could help.